# Whether Docker machine necessary for Ubuntu,if not how to TCP a Ubuntu docker daemon?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, tcp, docker-machine

I have installed docker on ubuntu machine to run docker on tcp in windows or mac machine
we need docker-machine whereas in ubuntu it not necessary since it is already
running on linux environment

If this is the case consider i have an image as below

```
ubuntu@ip-X-X-X-X:~$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
jenkins              latest              04c1dd56a3d8        3 weeks ago         713 MB
```

now i'm trying to run this using below command

```
ubuntu@ip-X-X-X-X:~$ sudo docker run -p 7878:7878 jenkins
```

after execution it is running propery

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-15-253:~$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                         NAMES
40e5f4212cf4        jenkins             "/bin/tini -- /usr..."   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7500->7500/tcp, 50000/tcp   kickass_lichterman
```

now if it a docker-machine we have tcp connection ip but in ubuntu machine
which ip i need to use to access this

my docker demon is running on some port found from below address

```
/var/run/docker.pid
```

My current docker environment running on below config

```
Docker Version: 17.03.1-ce
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: If you need to access jenkins, try `http://localhost:8080/jenkins` in browser.

Comment: No I'm running this on Amazon web service Ubuntu machine,even though if I access thorough IP not able to access

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the port of the docker process to a port on the host (Ubuntu AWS) machine using the "-P" option like "-P 8080:8080". Then you can access the jenkins instance using the URL suggested by Rao.

See the docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/

Comment: Yeah i agree even i bind the port "docker run -p 7878:7878 jenkins",my question is what will be the ip now ??

Comment: The IP is the same as the host machine the docker process is running on.

Comment: but i couldn't able to access any work around i need to do @hellified

Comment: but i couldn't able to access any work around i need to do @hellified